# How can I get Backbone router + Kendo UI Mobile (tabstrip) to work together?

Tags: kendo-ui

How can I get Backbone router + Kendo UI Mobile (tabstrip) to work together?

I am just getting started with Backbone and have been looking at using it with a UI. I was able to do this with Backbone and jQuery Mobile (JQM) by disabling JQM's routing as outlined in this post: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/

```
// Disable JQM routing
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});

// Backbone Router
// Create backbone view, append it to the body, and then use JQM to change to that page
home: function () {
    page = new HomeView();
    page.render();
    $('body').append( $(page.el) );
    $.mobile.changePage( $(page.el), {changeHash:false} );  
}
```

Working through the Kendo UI Mobile docs, I have this working page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <section data-role="layout" data-id="default">
        <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">My App</div>
        </header>

        <!--View content will render here-->

        <footer data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="tabstrip">
                <a class="tab-a" data-icon="home" href="#home">Home</a>
                <a class="tab-a" data-icon="bookmarks" href="#about">About</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </section>

    <div data-role="view" data-layout="default" id="home">Home Page</div>
    <div data-role="view" data-layout="default" id="about">About Page</div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

It has a tabstrip with 2 buttons that enables you to switch between the 2 views.

I can get it to work with a Backbone router - whereby the routes "home" and "about" are called as the tabstrip buttons are clicked, but cannot work out how to intercept the click events, enabling me to generate a view, append it to the DOM, and then ensure that the relevant tabstrip button class is changed to represent the selected state.

I tried adding a class to the tabstrip links - $('.tabstrip-link').click( function () { alert( 'Clicked' ); } ) - but to no avail (sporadically fired). How can I remove the views from between the body tags, and generate these via a Backbone route, append them to the Layout between the header and footer sections, and then let the tabstrip change go about it's business?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable the Kendo Router if you wish to use the Backbone router. The Kendo Router in mobile is not designed to be disabled. However at first glance, the following worked for me, if placed before creating your application.

```
kendo.mobile.Application.prototype._startHistory = function() {};
kendo.mobile.Application.prototype.router = {destroy: function() {}};
```

It works because Pane has it's own History management if the router is not created.